# Unable to add icon to Marker , Map V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Here is how i am adding marker to map

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(model.getLatLongfromService())
                    .title(model.getCoupon_name())
                    .snippet(model.getCoupon_id())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromFile(DataHolder.imageUrl
                            + model.getCoupon_image())));
```

- I am getting coupon_image in this format :  http://www.xyz.com/coupon21.jpg**
- I am getting this error when u run my app.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File http://test.xyz.de/uploads/company_logo/sample-logo-110x60.jpg contains a path separator

Can anyone help me to understand what the problem is ?

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that method BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromFile uses parameter String fileName, which represents name of the file(image) to load.
You supply image's http url (http://test.xyz.de/uploads/company_logo/sample-logo-110x60.jpg) instead of it.

You probably need to download the image first and then use BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap;

**EDIT:**
To download image, you can use some AsyncTask like this for example:

```
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> loadImageTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>(){
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bmImg = null;
            try { 
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
                conn.setDoInput(true);   
                conn.connect();     
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {       
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                bmImg = null;
            }

            return bmImg; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // TODO: do what you need with resulting bitmap - add marker to map
        }
    };
```

then don't forget to execute asynctask with proper parameter - String array containing url of image to download:

```
loadImageTask.execute(new String[]{yourImageUrl});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please suggest how can i download image from URL and Store it into Bitmap using Asyntask. I read some where that i need to use asyntask.