# Set marker icon on Google Maps v2 Android from URL

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I am unable to add the icon provided by the Google Places API to the marker. For example, I would like to have the icon returned from the JSON of Google Places API:

```
"icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png"
```

Here's how I am doing it now without adding the icon:

```
for (Place place : mNearPlaces.results) {
     LatLng placeLatLng = new LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat,
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(placeLatLng)
             .title(place.name));
}
```

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549031/unable-to-add-icon-to-marker-map-v2-android) and the answer suggested using some AsyncTask to download the image. Is there any other way to do this (that way seems slow)? Is there a standard way of setting the marker image provided by the Google Places API?

Here is the [Google Maps Android API v2 Documentation for Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can load url image to a GoogleMap mapMarker using following code. First set other properties like title, snippet, position etc....

```
  mapMarker= mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(Integer.toString(total_steps))
                    .snippet("Steps")
                    .position(new LatLng(current_lat,current_longi)));
            mapMarker.setTag("current_position");
            mapMarker.showInfoWindow();
            loadMarkerIcon(mapMarker);
```

After use a custom method to load a image for icon property. You can add Glide gradle link to project.

```
private void loadMarkerIcon(final Marker marker) {
        String burlImg = "Url_imagePath;
        Glide.with(this).load(burlImg)
                .asBitmap().fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                if(bitmap!=null){
                  //  Bitmap circularBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 150);
                    Bitmap mBitmap = getCircularBitmap(bitmap);
                    mBitmap = addBorderToCircularBitmap(mBitmap, 2, Color.WHITE,squareBitmapWidth);
                    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mBitmap);
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of libraries that help you view images from URL like: [URLImageViewhelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) unfortunately, you can't load images from URL without `AsyncTask` however all the libraries that help you view images from URL are using `Asynctask` so only you have to do is call the function.

the implementation of the library class are available within the github page.

Answer (score 0):

While calling .icon() do the following

```
 protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, String imageUrl) {

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    return googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmapFromLink(imageUrl))));
}
```

This method will convert the image url to bitmap

```
   public Bitmap getBitmapFromLink(String link) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("asfwqeds", e.getMessage());
        }
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("asfwqeds", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, an exception will occur in connection.connect() saying android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. To handle this Exception add this code in you oncreate or before adding the marker

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```