# google map api v2 add icon from url android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a project that retrieves latitude and longitude from web service and I add them to google map markers. I want to add custom icon for the markers from url.

```
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(dlat,Dlong))
                    .title(m.group(9))
                    .draggable(false)                                           
                    .snippet(m.group(1)+" "+m.group(10)));
```

How I can add `.icon` with a custom icon from a link?

Comment: Here is the detailed answer including code snippet
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929527/8663316

Comment: Here is the detailed answer including code snippet
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929527/8663316

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use this method and use returned bitmap to display in map





public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer i manage to do it similar with your answer

Comment: Could you please explain how your code snippet can be used to change the marker icon with respect to the quesntion? Thanks.

Comment: I implemented this and while it worked (after adding in the permitAll strictmode threadpolicy) it was extremely slow, especially with many markers... is this process basically not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
                        URL url = new URL(Lurl);
                        /** Creating an http connection to communcate with url */
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        /** Connecting to url */
                        urlConnection.connect();
                        /** Reading data from url */
                        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        /** Creating a bitmap from the stream returned from the url */
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
                    }finally{
                        iStream.close();
                    }
```

this worked for me