# get image from server and show as marker icon using Volley

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, android-volley, marker

I'm fetching  marker icon URL from server using volley library.

```
String icon_url = catObj.getString("icon_url");
```

and then assigning the icon_url to the variable declared in **MyMarker** class

```
 this.mIconUrl = icon_url;
```

Now in setUpMap method I'm stuck how to replace marker icon with image I'm fetching from server. Here is the code for this:

```
 for(MyMarker myMarker : markers)
 {
     Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(myMarker.getmLatLng())
     .title(myMarker.getmLabel())
     .snippet(myMarker.getmIcon())
     .icon( ??? ));  //myMarker.getmIconUrl won't work as it return String
 }
```

I've also tried from this link but it shows the image in ImageView:

http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-example-to-load-image-from-internet/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use BitmapFactory to render custom pattern. You can use similar to load bitmap from URL :

[Android google mapv2 icon from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500229/android-google-mapv2-icon-from-url)

Or this just replace HttpUrlConnection with Volley :

[google map api v2 add icon from url android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732712/google-map-api-v2-add-icon-from-url-android)

And when you get bitmap you can use `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));`

Answer (score 0):

For getting Images using **Volley** you have to first create an instance of `MarkerOptions` and then use **Volley ImageLoader** to get images from server and then set image to marker after you get it's bitmap. you may possibly have something like this:

```
ImageLoader imageloader =VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();

 for(MyMarker myMarker : markers)
  {
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
          .position(myMarker.getmLatLng());

    imageloader.get(myMarker.getmIconUrl(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) 
         {
           Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
           if (bitmap != null) {
              markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
               //add marker to your map using below codes 
              // mapMarkers is a HashMap of your markers and your possible values for that location(eg. id,name,..)
              Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
              mapMarkers.put(marker, myMarker.getLocationId());
           }
         }
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         }
     });
  }
```