# Android Map Marker pin with dynamic image from url

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I want to creat map pins that have an image inside them that comes from a server's url. I create the view of the pin, use picasso to get the image and then make the view a bitmap to use it as the pin's icon. BUT the image is not shown...I can only see the borders I have put in the view.

I think that this is caused by the transformation of the view to a Bitmap, as picasso gets the image async so when it converts it to bitmap, then the image is not in the view yet.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

```
private View preparePinView () {


    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.places_pin_layout, null);
    ImageView image = marker.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image1url).fit().centerCrop().into(image1);

    return marker;
}

// Convert a view to bitmap
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

--- Set the view in the marker

```
View pinView = preparePinView();
Bitmap placePinBM = createDrawableFromView(getActivity(), pinView);

Marker pinMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(markerLatLng)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(placePinBM)));
```

Comment: Here is the complete solution along with code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929527/8663316

Answer (score 2):

You can pass Url from onCreate an load custom marker

```
 private class LoadMarker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Get bitmap from server
            Bitmap overlay;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return overlay;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            LatLng pLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            // If received bitmap successfully, draw it on our drawable
            if (bitmap != null) {
                View custom_layout = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_marker, null);
                ImageView iv_category_logo = (ImageView) custom_layout.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
                Bitmap pinbit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 40, 60, false);
                iv_category_logo.setImageBitmap(pinbit);
                BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(mContext, custom_layout));
                // Add the new marker to the map
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(pLatLng)
                        .title("")
                        .snippet("")
                        .icon(bitmapDescriptor));
            } else {
                // Add the new marker to the map
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(pLatLng)
                        .title("")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_marker)));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Convert a view to bitmap
         *
         * @param context
         * @param view
         * @return
         */
        private Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init your map here

    new LoadMarker().execute();
}
```

view_custom_marker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_marker">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_app" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Image sample
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onSucess` callback, like this:

```
private View preparePinView () {

    View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.places_pin_layout, null);
    final ImageView image = marker.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image1url).fit().centerCrop().into(image1, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Bitmap placePinBM = createDrawableFromView(context, image);

            Marker pinMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(markerLatLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(placePinBM)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });

    return marker;
}

// Convert a view to bitmap
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```