# Custom marker icon from image URL GoogleMap API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-markers, picasso

I have one problem.

My goal is to load custom image of company and show it instead default marker icon.

But I have faced with the problem.

Icons are shown only if I close and open activity again.

Here is my code for adding markers to the map.

```
private void addMarkerToTheMap(GoogleMapInfoBundle infoBundle) {
        if (infoBundle.placeMarker) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(infoBundle.company.getLatitude(), infoBundle.firm.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(infoBundle.company.getName())
                    .snippet(infoBundle.company.getAddress())
                    .position(latLng);
            Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            try {
                Picasso.with(this).load(NetworkUtils.getUrlOfScaledImage(infoBundle.company.getLogo(), DEFAULT_ICON_SCALE_PERCENTAGE)).into(new PicassoMarker(marker));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
```

And `PicassoMarker`

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
    Marker mMarker;

    public PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

In this case it displays default icon [image].

I have tried to make it in another way like this

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(infoBundle.company.getName())
                        .snippet(infoBundle.company.getAddress())
                        .position(latLng);
  try {
                Picasso.with(this).load(NetworkUtils.getUrlOfScaledImage(infoBundle.company.getLogo(), DEFAULT_ICON_SCALE_PERCENTAGE)).into(new PicassoMarker(mGoogleMap, markerOptions));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                // Do nothing
            }
```

And add marker to the map in callback after image has been downloaded.

```
   @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
    }
```

It doesn't show any marker in this case.

But in both cases if I close `Activity` and open it again everything will be displayed correctly with icons as it should.

I have no idea what can cause such problem. It seems `GoogleMap` caches icon image or something else.

I have a little experience working with `GoogleMaps API`, maybe I am missing something.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the complete solution along with code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929527/8663316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in `GoogleMap` or `SupportMapFragment` it was in `Picasso`, not exactly in `Picasso` but in my flow.

The thing you should always remember using custom `Target` classes is that internally `Picasso` uses `WeakReference` for storing `Target` objects, so if you will just create new `Target` directly inside `Picasso` call it will be destroyed by garbage collector.

`Picasso` provides `Callback` class, so you can create anonymous class instead and that you class will hold the reference.

But one thing that is I am missing `Callback` class that provides `Bitmap` in response like `Target`(but targets are mostly used by custom views).

So I have found such solution, it ugly, but here it is.

I have created special list for storing target objects, not to be garbaged.

```
  Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            mMarkerCompanyMap.put(marker, infoBundle.firm);
            try {
                PicassoMarkerTarget markerTarget = new PicassoMarkerTarget(marker, mImageLoadingCallback);
                mPicassoMarkerTargetList.add(markerTarget);
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(NetworkUtils.getUrlOfScaledImage(infoBundle.firm.getLogo(), DEFAULT_ICON_SCALE_PERCENTAGE))
                        .into(markerTarget);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                // Do nothing
            }
```

I am passing `mImageLoadingCallback` for having callback back to the activity from `Target`
And it looks like.

```
private Callback mImageLoadingCallback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Logger.logError("IMAGE LOADED IN CALLBACK " + mPendingImagesCount);
            if (mPendingImagesCount <= 0) {
                mPicassoMarkerTargetList.clear();
            } else {
                mPendingImagesCount--;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            // You may start laughing, but just for the sake of not duplicating code
            onSuccess();
        }
    };
```

This callback can be used for other purposes, but now only for clear array.

And of course `PicassoMarkerTarget`

```
   @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        mDownloadListenerCallback.onSuccess();
        Logger.logError("IMAGE LOADED IN PICASSO MARKER TARGET");
    }
```

This is ugly solution but maybe this callback can be helpful in the future.

Please, if you have idea how to make solution better - please share it.
Thanks.